# Apply AuthorizeForScopesAttribute in the whole application

Tags: razor-pages, authorize-attribute, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a Razor pages application.
I am using MS Identity Platform Application. Now I need to acquire silently the tokes so I can call some APIs.

Everything works, but I have a portion of code is repeated for all pages:

```
[Microsoft.Identity.Web.AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "AdminApi:Scope")]
public class MyModel : PageModel
{
   ...
}
```

Exist a way to apply that attribute to the whole my application?

I have tryed something like that:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderApplicationModelConvention(
        "MyArea", "/MyAreaFolder",
        model => model.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.Identity.Web.AuthorizeForScopesAttribute() { ScopeKeySection = "AdminApi:Scope" }));
})
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

I have also tryed using:
`AddAreaFolderApplicationModelConvention`
`AddAreaPageApplicationModelConvention`
`AddPageApplicationModelConvention`

No solution works. What can I try?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Following the example at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/Startup.cs it seems that you should be able to do just that with [EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebappauthenticationbuilder.enabletokenacquisitiontocalldownstreamapi?view=azure-dotnet) in the services configuration of your project

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    //Other parts of the authentication builder
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(
        options =>                
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); //<-- use your own options
        },
        new string[] { Configuration["AdminApi:Scope"] } //<--Your scope(s) 
    )
    //More parts of the authentication builder;
```

I haven't tested this solution, though.